# C++ Inheritance, Unresolved externals?

Tags: c++, inheritance

Any ideas why I keep getting this error? 
http://codepad.org/jPQzMWvG

Comment: Aside from the error: you should never put a `using namespace X;` in a header, it actually takes away the point of namespaces.

Comment: Instead of posting links to codepad, posting the code and the actual compiler error directly in your question would be preferable.

Comment: ... just remove from the code anything that you know is irrelevant. save us time and we might save you time.

Answer (score 3):

You declared a destructor in the header (line 36), but you haven't defined it in the source code. Add this to the source code, and you should be fine :

```
Entity::~Entity()
{
  // do the cleanup here
}
```

Comment: There are raw pointer members, the proper destructor probably won't be empty.

Comment: @MarkRansom Right. I am not sure why the pointers are used in the first place. I also see lots of other problems in the code. To summarize, it could use a proper cleanup.

Comment: @Barnes Noble -- if VJo's answer helped you the most, please accept his answer by clicking the check next to it. That's how stackoverflow works!

Answer (score 1):

Your class definition includes a destructor `~Entity` but there's no implementation for it in the `Entity.cpp` file.

Answer (score 1):

You've declared a destructor `~Entity()` (and also `~Block()`), but not implemented them anywhere. If the destructors are necessary, then implement them; otherwise, remove the declarations.

By the way, you should post the code in the question rather than an external website.